# Как добавить второе значение по ключу, в уже существующую пару, при этом не использовать список

Tags: python, dict

Мне нужно в словарь `dict_bundle = {'tree': 'дерево'}`, по ключу добавить еще значение, чтобы получилось `{'tree':'дерево', 'листья'}`. Возможно ли это сделать не используя списка, т.е. `{'tree':['дерево', 'листья']}`, можно ли это избежать?

Comment: Если Вам это понадобилось, значит Вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: Какой-то контейнер вам для этого всё-равно понадобится - список, множество, словарь. Та конструкция, которую вы написали как желаемую, в питоне не является синтаксически корректной.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, к сожалению, это невозможно, поскольку чтобы хранить массив вы должны использовать тип данных соотвествующий массиву: `list, set`

Comment: n1tr0xs, тогда каким образом по ключу добавить новое значение в список, как получить хотя бы это  {'tree':['дерево', 'листья']}

Comment: Можно еще так {'tree': {'дерево': 'листья'}}

Comment: d["tree"] = [d["tree"], "ветки"]

Answer (score 0):

> тогда каким образом по ключу добавить новое значение в список, как получить хотя бы это {'tree':['дерево', 'листья']}

```py
attributes = (('tree', 'дерево'), ('tree', 'листья'),)
objects = dict()

for item, attribute in attributes:
    objects[item] = objects.get(item, []) + [attribute]

print(objects)
# {'tree':['дерево', 'листья']}
```

Comment: from collections import defaultdict

Comment: @Lecron, графиня изменившимся лицом бежит пруду